# ArrayAdapter with class

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

So guys, in my project i'm using custom listView's and at first i only passed to the adapter String's, but now i want to pass class's, cause i wanna pass more information. But i don't why it won't let me!
Here's my adapter with strings yet:

```
class costum_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public costum_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> horarios) {
        super(context, R.layout.costum_listview ,horarios);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater horarioInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View costumView = horarioInflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_listview, parent, false);

        String singleHorario = getItem(position);
        TextView hora = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Hora);
        TextView nota = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Nota);

        hora.setText(singleHorario);
        nota.setText(" ");

        return costumView;
    }
}
```

Now, i thought in order to receive class's i only needed to change the argument, where is ArrayList horarios i would change to ArrayList horarios. "horario" is my class, here:

```
public class horario{
    public String hora;
    public int destino;
    public int note;

    public horario(String horaIn, int Destino, int Nota){
        hora = horaIn;
        destino = Destino;
        note = Nota;
    }
}
```

I'm using ArrayList too. But i filled the ArrayList with objects from the class.
When i try to change the arguments on the adapter to receive my class, it doesn't recognize it, i start typing "horario" but it's not recognized, i don't know why because i have that class in the other file.

Comment: Did you notice you have a typo in your constructor? costum_adapter instead of custom_adapter.

Comment: Yeah i know, that's because when i was creating the java file i pronunced it wrong and then i had to declared all with costum_adapter otherwise would give error.

Comment: make sure you are extend properly do as public class extends ArrayAdapter<horario>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to solve my own problem. My issue was that i couldn't change "ArrayList" to "ArrayList", horario being my class i wanted but that's because "horario" was declared in a bigger class. So i just had to change to "ArrayList", "mostraHorario" being the bigger class.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
class costum_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<horario> {

 public costum_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<horario> horarios) {
 super(context, R.layout.costum_listview ,horarios);
 }
```

Comment: As i explained in the description, that makes sense and i tried it. But the problem is that it won't recognize my class. if i change to "ArrayList<horario>" gives me error on the "horario" cause it's not recognizing it

Comment: If the problem is that it doesn't recognize horario, then just import it to your class.

Comment: import it where ? how ?

Comment: to your Adapter class file. Just check what package is horario belongs to, and import it to your adapter.

Comment: Can you write in code what you are trying to explain ? I'm not getting it :x

Comment: e.g.:
import com.appname.com.model.horario;

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public costum_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<horario> horarios) {
        super(context, R.layout.costum_listview ,horarios);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater horarioInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View costumView = horarioInflater.inflate(R.layout.costum_listview, parent, false);

    String singleHorario = getItem(position).getHora();
    String singlenote = getItem(position).getNote();
    TextView hora = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Hora);
    TextView nota = (TextView) costumView.findViewById(R.id.Nota);

    hora.setText(singleHorario);
    nota.setText(singlenote);

    return costumView;
}
```

Model Class

```
public class horario{
public String hora;
public int destino;
public int note;

public horario(String horaIn, int Destino, int Nota){
    hora = horaIn;
    destino = Destino;
    note = Nota;
}

public String getHora() {
    return hora;
}

public void setHora(String hora) {
    this.hora = hora;
}

public int getDestino() {
    return destino;
}

public void setDestino(int destino) {
    this.destino = destino;
}

public int getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void setNote(int note) {
    this.note = note;
}
}
```

Comment: As i said to the answer before and in the description. I already tried to change "ArrayList<String>" to "ArrayList<horario>", obviously that's what i need to have. But the problem is that when i write horario in there it doesn't recognize it, gives error "cannot resolve symbol horario". It doesn't recognize my class, i don't know why